# After catching exception, C++ program aborts on return

Tags: c++, exception

I've looked around and found some similar issues but my particular one is stumping me.

Here is a code fragment in a test program, this is in the main() function:

```
try {
      // some code that throws an exception
} catch(myexception& err) {
    std::cout << "Shouldn't have encounterd an error\n";
    std::cout << err.what() << endl;
}

cout << "Returning\n";
return 0;
```

I'm catching the exception and printing the messages. Then I print the "Returning" message and return. On the return I'm getting

Returning

Aborted (core dumped)

The stackdump tells me nothing. I am building on Windows 7 under Cygwin using g++ 4.7.3, can someone clue me in as to what might be happening and how to trap it?

--->
Kudos to  David Rodríguez. You were right, a destructor attempted to free some area of memory that was already free.

Comment: have you stepped through your code with a debugger?

Comment: In my experience, it tends to be data corruption somewhere up the path.  I'd see how your custom exception "myexception" is handling memory.  Make sure it's initializing what it needs to function and cleans up nicely after itself in the destructor.  I have a feeling theirs a wayward allocation somewhere that is getting either double-deallocated or a dereference to cleaned up memory.

Comment: First thing I think is an overwrite caused the exception, and you're returning into a ruined stack.

Comment: Looks like there is a destructor that is crashing your app...

Comment: Without seeing more of what is going on, I am not sure if anyone can do more than give guesses.

Comment: seems the bug is in myexception